# Use older timepicker in Android project

Tags: android, timepicker

I like the older style time picker for Android better than the new one. Below is what the old one looks like, from the Lampshade project for Philips Hue: [image: nice time picker]

My question: how can I get this time picker look in my projects for Android 5 using Android Studio 1.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you [this](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) to get below (Material) style

[image]

Comment: Got it working - so much better than the stock pickers!